# How can I build deterministically with both Visual Studio and MSBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, deterministic

I have reached a point where I can repeat the build in Visual Studio 2019 and have a deterministic build... and the same from when I build on the command line using MSBuild v16. Unfortunately, the assembly that is output when building using VS2019 is different than when building using MSBuild.

I understand the concept of the deterministic build process, along with the myriad of factors taken into account by the compiler when it makes its choices. What I need to do is figure out exactly what Visual Studio is doing during the compile process so that I can replicate using MSBuild. From what I have seen, Visual Studio bypasses MSBuild and goes straight to the compiler (which doesn't make this any easier).

Has anybody attempted this and had success with this? Maybe you attempted it and gave up? Answers to both are equally helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostics logging and compare the two cases. Deterministic build is a feature of Roslyn C# compiler I think, so logging should show if the right compiler is being used.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build deterministically with both Visual Studio and MSBuild?

**In fact**, to build C# projects, VS IDE call **MSBuild** to build projects. VS IDE calls MSBuild to build the project, which itself is consistent with MSBuild compiled through the command line. The MSBuild exists under  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin` in VS2019 folder.

It's just that VS IDE integrates a lot of tools. If you install some extensions or tools related to build in VS IDE, it may affect the final build. MSBuild(command line) is a pure compilation tool, VS IDE will call it to build.

**---------------------------**

**First**, I wonder if you use **VS IDE** and its **Developer Command Prompt for VS**(exist under VS2019 IDE) to build your projects separately. If so, I think you should make sure whether the command-line arguments are consistent with the build parameters in the VS IDE.

At the first, please disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** in case they affect MSBuild in VS IDE.

Then, make sure that when you build your projects, you should pay attention to the **Configuration**(`Debug` or `Release`) or **Platform**(`x64`,`x86` or `Any CPU`) of every projects.

Then you should do these in MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild xxxx.csproj -t:build -p:Configuration=xxx -p:Platform=xxx
```

Make sure that the build instructions are consistent.

**--------------------------**

**Second**, when you use Build Tool for VS2019 in another single agent(it can be installed separately without VS IDE) and if so, you should make sure that its version is the same as VS IDE.（Build Tool version `v16.xxx` is same as VS IDE version `v16.xxx`） And different versions of MSBuild will have slightly different builds, so be consistent.

**Actually**, MSBuild builds c # projects using [csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) to compile files, so both VS IDE and MSBuild are consistent for c# files. There is no problem of different compilers using `csc`.

**In addition**, to see more deatiled: you can check the detailedd build log by this way:

In **VS IDE**:

`Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed`.

In **MSBuild**:

```
msbuild xxxx.csproj -t:build -p:Configuration=xxx -p:Platform=xxx -v:detailed
```